# Why so many "reserved built-in symbol"-s in python

Tags: python, keyword

I am learning Python. Up to now, `filter`, `id` and other words generate warnings `Warning: assignment to reserved built-in symbol`. Well, I am designing **filters** and assigning **id**-s to each, and this warning is forcing me to use underscores all over the place.

C's reserved keywords are either shortened words e.g. `int` or not very often used English words e.g. `volatile`. How do I cope with the extreme readability of the Python programming language, that is forcing me to make my own programs unreadable?

Comment: It is not Python giving that error; those are not reserved keywords.

Answer (score 8):

That warning is nothing to do with Python per se.

A quick search with Google seems to indicate that the warning is generated when you use Eclipse with PyDev, so the answer would seem to be look in the PyDev documentation to find out how to turn it off.

This stackoverflow question may be of help: [Suppress warnings in PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254015/suppress-warnings-in-pydev)

Comment: I think the warning should have been: redefining xxx, are you sure ...

Answer (score 4):

These are not reserved keywords, as such - you *can* replace them. It is only a warning, in which the IDE tells you it is probably not a good idea to do so, as it may break code that will be copy-pasted in and out of your module, and may make your code confusing without full context.

Here are the reserved keywords in Python ([2](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and [3](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords))

```
False (3)  class      finally    is         return
None  (3)  continue   for        lambda     try
True  (3)  def        from       nonlocal   while
and        del        global     not        with
as         elif       if         or         yield
assert     else       import     pass       exec  (2)
break      except     in         raise      print (2)
```

Only Python2's `exec` and `print` are sensible variable names. I assume this is part of the reason why they are not reserved in Python3 anymore.

Python is designed to be readable, so it uses readable english words for type names. `id` is probably not a good idea, yes. and maybe `list`, `dict` etc. should have been `List`, `Dict` etc. but it is too late to change that now.

If you design a filter, you can call it `Filter`. same goes for `Id` or `ID`.