# pydevd warnings in Visual Studio Code Debug Console

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, pydev

I've been searching for some time but couldn't find any related problem.

When using Visual Studio Code with Python extension for debugging on large elements, computing a representation or getting an attribute may take some time.

In these cases a warning like:

> pydevd warning: Computing repr of ... (DataFrame) was slow (took 0.84s)

is printed to the debug console (also see https://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html).

Even more annoying, a popup turns up on the lower left corner.

Is there any way to disable these warnings and in particular this popup concerning this warning?

I have tried more or less everything what I found with respect to logging and warning in Visual Studio Code debugging.

A minimal example would look like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file of 1GB')

df
```

The warning is not a warning on a particular line but a warning given by the debugger everytime the large object is used (e.g. just printed or with an operation df.some_operation()).

1. [Screenshot of warning at breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whPIB.png)
2. [Screenshot of warning everytime the object is printed in the debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdRYf.png)

Comment: Die you already tried something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254015/suppress-warnings-in-pydev#:~:text=In%20PyDev%2C%20whenever%20there's%20an,%2Fwarning%20will%20be%20ignored).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TomHammerbacher The problem is different as this is not a warning with respect to one particular line but a warning that is given with the execution of the debugger anytime an operation is done on a large object.

Answer (score 33):

As Fabio Zadrozny suggested, you can change the environment variable, `PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT`, to the preferred time.

I fixed it by adding the following line to the "*launch.json*" file in Visual Studio Code.

```
"env": {"PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "2"}
```

So my "*launch.json*" looks something like this:

```
...
"launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "2"}
        }
    ]
}
...
```

Comment: That is great. Thanks a lot, this solves my problem. May I ask where you find these things documented? I have gone through the whole VSCode debugging, python extensions settings & documentation as well as searched on the PyDev website but found nothing...

Comment: I've added it to launch.json. Maybe my VScode is configured differently from yours

Comment: This one makes the warning appear as pop-up, instead of warning in terminal. Which is good enough to solve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm debugging the jupyter cell in VSCode, I don't know why not work.

Answer (score 8):

What you can do here is set an environment variable to change the timeout before it's reported.

Note that the default is 0.15s (a small number is used because there are cases where thousands of such small delays during the repr are given and the debugger can appear to be stuck when it's actually because user-code is too slow to compute its repr).

You can change it setting an environment variable such as:

`PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT=2`

(this will change the timeout to 2 seconds).

Note that the real fix here would be pandas improving its `repr` implementation so that it'd be faster...

Comment: That is great. Thanks a lot, this solves my problem. May I ask where you find these things documented? I have gone through the whole VSCode debugging, python extensions settings & documentation as well as searched on the PyDev website but found nothing...

Comment: Unfortunately I think this isn't really documented anywhere -- right now this answer is probably the best documentation around it ;)

Comment: how do you know about it then? and how do you set this environment variable?

Comment: @DarQ See Lasse Madsen's answer below. This is very helpful.

Comment: I did see his answer but unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried modifying launch.json to no avail.

note that my warning is a bit different:
`pydevd warning: Computing repr of soup (BeautifulSoup) was slow (took 1.00s)`


note sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Is there a way to set this for all configurations? I have ~50 debug launch configurations and it'd be a pain to do it for all of them... thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can set the environment variables in your OS (which should then be inherited when you start VSCode again).

Answer (score 1):

Had the issue.
On my Ubuntu environment, I just declared the variable:

```
$ export PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT=10
```

Then ran VSCODE and verified in the terminal that the variable is set:

```
$ echo $PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT
10
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this to the `launch.json` worked for me.

```
"env": {
            "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION": "1"
        }
```

If you are using Django debugger, your `launch.json` should look like:

```
{

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
        ],
        "django": true,
        "env": {
            "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION": "1"
        }
    },
    
]
```

}