# Fix the following: "pydevd warning: Computing repr of <something> was slow (took 0.35s)" in VS CODE

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm working with Python with VSCode and I'm struggling with the following since this year:

```
pydevd warning: Computing repr of mlb (MyLibrary) was slow (took 0.35s)
Source: Debug Unit Test
```

This message appears for a varieties of packages, but the fix reported here:
[pydevd warnings in Visual Studio Code Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695716/pydevd-warnings-in-visual-studio-code-debug-console)
is not working. I followed the relative suggestions to change the variable `PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT` in `settings.json`:

```
"launch": {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "10"
            }
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
},
```

I also tried to apply the same to `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {"PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "10"},
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is the VS Code version:

```
Version: 1.70.2 (user setup)
Commit: e4503b30fc78200f846c62cf8091b76ff5547662
Date: 2022-08-16T05:35:13.448Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

Do you see anything wrong? any other suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a minimization case to reproduce the problem

Comment: I'm not sure if I can, indeed mlb is a local library

Comment: Did you run the file in debug mode?

Comment: Correct, I'm debugging

Comment: As someone who has the same issue - to reproduce the message, generate a large file (dataframe of 1000 rows or so) and call repr on it. The TIMEOUT env should increase the timeout but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If you are executing from interactive window, the environment variable needs to be set elsewhere (in settings): "jupyter.runStartupCommands":["import os", "os.environ['PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT']='2'"]